# How to get the list of divs inside another div in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, children

Following is my html code.

```
<div class="panels" id="panels">
   <div class = 'panel' id = 'panel1' title = 'Learners Status' ></div>
   <div class = 'panel' id = 'panel2' title = 'ILR Status' ></div>
   <div class = 'panel' id = 'panel3' title = 'Test Graph' ></div>
</div>
```

I want to get all panel divs inside the 'panels' div.

Following code is not working for me.

```
var children = $("div.panels").children('div');
alert(children.length);
```

Comment: Define 'not working'.

Comment: Working fine : http://jsfiddle.net/frcsu2bk/. Are you loading jQuery? Are you waiting the DOM to be ready?

Comment: Yes I am doing that after page loading completes, yes JQuery is loading properly as well.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Not any errors appearing, when I remove the class attribute from inner divs then it works OK.

Comment: Please use double-quotes `"` on attributes for best compatibility and remove the spaces around the ` = `: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/frcsu2bk/1/

Comment: Is there any jquery version issue?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your code is not at the bottom of the page, in which case you have to explicitly require the code to wait for `DOM ready` event:

```
$(function() {
    var children = $("div.panels").children('div.panel');
    alert(children.length);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var children = $('div.panels').children('div.panel');
  children.each(function() {
    $('pre.out').append( 'id: ' + this.id + ', title: ' + this.title + '<br>' );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panels" id="panels">
   <div class = 'panel' id = 'panel1' title = 'Learners Status' ></div>
   <div class = 'panel' id = 'panel2' title = 'ILR Status' ></div>
   <div class = 'panel' id = 'panel3' title = 'Test Graph' ></div>
</div>


<h1>Children Details</h1>
<pre class="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that but was not 100% sure that OP's `..doing that after page loading completes` means the same thing as `DOM ready`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function displayPanelsTitles() {
      var mainPanel = document.getElementById("panels").childNodes;
      
      alert("Panel 1 : " + mainPanel[1].title + " Panel 2 : " + mainPanel[3].title + " Panel 5 : " + mainPanel[5].title);
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8" />
        <title> test </title>
      </head>
      <body onload = "displayPanelsTitles()">
       <div class="panels" id="panels">
         <div class = 'panel' id = 'panel1' title = 'Learners Status' ></div>
         <div class = 'panel' id = 'panel2' title = 'ILR Status' ></div>
         <div class = 'panel' id = 'panel3' title = 'Test Graph' ></div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This one extract each div title. Hope it helps !

Comment: Alright, I used `.childNodes` to get all child from an element, and then I display their title using the index of their tag.

Comment: @Max723 - So you're saying that Karl-André Gagnon's fiddle in the comments didn't work for you?